# getting font size in pixels

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

At the moment I define the size of a grid-row-size static with

```
self.myGrid.SetDefaultRowSize(16)
```

I know thats not pretty, but until now there were no trouble with this solution.
But when using Windows scaling option for display( best resolution, scaling to 125%) the font writes over the bounderies of the rows. So the question:

How do I get the font-size, also when windows scaling is true?

Comment: wx.Font's have a method GetPixelSize http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Font.html#Font.GetPixelSize, if that doesn't take the scaling into account you could always try scaling up the returned values by the same factor.